# my markers don't appear using google maps api v3, using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i know this question appears a lot but i've done this three times and the markers still don't appear, for some reason when i call data.Latitude and data.Longitude when i move the cursor over Latitude or Longitude it appears undefined. I did this guiding myself with a tutorial i found on youtube which it works perfectly but it doesn't work to me. I'm new using php

Here's my php code getting my data from the database(im using MySQL).

```
<?php

 class location
{
   public $RouteID;
   public $Latitude;
   public $Longitude;
   public $Battery;
   public $DateObtained;
   public $ID_DEVICE;
   public $tableName = "geografia";

  function setRouteID($RouteID) { $this->RouteID = $RouteID; }
  function getRouteID() { return $this->RouteID; }
  function setLatitude($Latitude) { $this->Latitude = $Latitude; }
  function getLatitude() { return $this->Latitude; }
  function setLongitude($Longitude) { $this->Longitude = $Longitude; }
  function getLongitude() { return $this->Longitude; }
  function setBattery($Battery) { $this->Battery = $Battery; }
  function getBattery() { return $this->Battery; }
  function setDate($DateObtained) { $this->DateObtained = $DateObtained; }
  function getDate() { return $this->DateObtained; }
  function setID_DEVICE($ID_DEVICE) { $this->ID_DEVICE = $ID_DEVICE; }
  function getID_DEVICE() { return $this->ID_DEVICE; }


  public function getLocations(){

    require_once("db/DbConnect.php");

    $sql = "SELECT RouteID,Latitude,Longitude,Battery,DateObtained FROM $this->tableName
            WHERE RouteID IS NOT NULL";

            while ($stmt = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
              return $stmt->fetch_all();
            }
  }

  public function getAllLocations(){
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbName = 'intecespejo';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $pass = '';

    $connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser , $pass, $dbName);
    require_once("db/DbConnect.php");

    $sql = "SELECT Latitude,Longitude,Battery,DateObtained FROM $this->tableName";
            while ($stmt = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
              return $stmt->fetch_all();
            }
  }


}
```

Here im calling the function from locations.php(the code above)

The first call is just to show one row data and the other is to show everything, later i will change that.

```
<?php
   require 'locations.php';
   $Geo = new location;
   $coll = $Geo->getLocations();
   $coll = json_encode($coll, true);
   echo '<div id="data">' . $coll . '</div>';

   $allData = $Geo->getAllLocations();
   $allData = json_encode($allData, true);
   echo '<div id="allData">' . $allData . '</div>';
   ?>
```

And here's my javascript code

```
var map;

function loadMap(){
 var local = new google.maps.LatLng(18.487957, -69.961759) //{lat: 18.487957, lng: -69.961759}
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: local,
        zoom: 10
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: local,
        map: map
      });

  var cdata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML);
  //console.log(cdata);

  var DataLoc = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('allData').innerHTML);
  showAllData(DataLoc);


}

function showAllData(DataLoc){
  debugger;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(DataLoc, function(data){
    //var localizacion = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
    console.log(data);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude),
      map: map
     });
  }) 

}
```

Sorry if i'm asking the same question as other posts but i just can't figure out what's the problem and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check the console if any error has got logged ?

Comment: @soccerway oh right i forgot to mention that, no error appears in the console, it prints out the json data perfectly.

Comment: Can you show the json data please ? Is the 'property' name mentioned for the latitude and longitude is same as written in data.Latitude, data.Longitude ?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but you do know that the debugger statement stops code execution, right?

Comment: @frederickramirez: Your code is working for me, I have put a sample json data into <div id="allData"> and tested it. By the way I have removed the debugger line, please see the https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/g82m576k/

Comment: @lucas the debugger was just to see the data that it was returning, because of that i said when i place the cursor on Latitude it says undefined

Comment: @soccerway i see, thanks, i tried cleaning the cache too to see if it was that and still the same, but thanks for clearing that out for me.

Comment: @frederickramirez: Few things to consider, a) Check that you are calling the Google Api <script> line first and then put your javascript code. b) Try the Zoom level set to smaller value in maps to see if there are markers already loaded for locations ( zoom out). c)Double check if the latitude and longitude value are 'real' value of places so that the map can identify those places.

Comment: @soccerway already did all of those, all of the locations i had place in the database had been taken from real places